# What's a good setup for Arcade Mode?

Tags: streetpass-mii-plaza, streetpass-squad-mii-force

Arcade Mode is a pain. Luckily, I have enough people and coins stored up that I can buy effectively whatever I want - subject of course to the limit of three chosen colours and seven random colours (not counting those I get for free by StreetPassing). So, with three weapons of choice, which ones should I get to have the easiest time through Arcade Mode?

I suspect there's three ways to go about this:

- **Offensively**, where the goal is to kill everything as fast as possible to reduce the number of attacks that need dodging, which needs weapons designed to destroy lots of things quickly.
- **Defensively**, where the goal is to block attacks and dodge fire more than kill things, which needs the weapons that are capable of blocking things.
- **Speciality**, where the three weapons chosen are to make specific levels easier while leaving the other ones open (such as picking Piercing Laser so 3-3 is a cakewalk).

It would also be nice to know what single colour would be best for hard mode (only one weapon allowed), though not necessary.